# extracting repetitive cells from matrices in elements of cell array

Tags: matlab

Apologies if terminology is loose or incorrect. A newbie to Matlab here.

I have an < Nx1 cell> **'A'** and each N element measures < **some multiple of 48 (which varies)** x3 double> constructed using:

```
A=arrayfun(@(x) A(A(:,end)==x,:), unique(A(:,end)), 'UniformOutput', false);
```

I'm trying to extract the rows from 4 of the 48 slots for all multiples of 48, retaining the information for the entire row.

I've tried variants of

```
cell2mat(vertcat...
```

without success and would really appreciate any assistance, or even a suitable link.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Maybe post a minimal example with a small input and desires output

Comment: How do you define the "4 of the 48" - the first 4 of every sequence? How do you want the result, another cell array with one cell per slot, or just matrix with all information gathered together?

Comment: More specifically, I've a <35 x 1> cell. Each of the 35 elements represent over a years data broken into half hour timeframes (column1) (so a <25730 x 3 double> or a <25682 x 3 double> in elements with missing days). Eventually I would like to get a ratio of the average of the 35th-38th element (column2) of each day versus the average remainder of the day (column2). I've tried to frame the query such that I can extract rows 35,36,37,38,83,84,85,86,..25717,25718,25719,25720 and complete ratios etc. later. The output would be in a <2144 x 3 double> for each element. Thanks again

Comment: in a simpler example
A = {{1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9;10,11,12;13,14,15;16,17,18;19,20,21;22,23,24;25,26,27;28,29,30};{31,32,33;34,35,36;37,38,39;40,41,42;43,44,45;46,47,48;49,50,51;52,53,54;55,56,57;58,59,60};{61,62,63;64,65,66;67,68,69;70,71,72;73,74,75;76,77,78;79,80,81;82,83,84;85,86,87;88,89,90};{91,92,93;94,95,96;97,98,99;100,101,102;103,104,105;106,107,108;109,110,111;112,113,114;115,116,117;118,119,120}};

A = 

    {10x3 cell}
    {10x3 cell}
    {10x3 cell}
    {10x3 cell}


to extract B

Comment: B = {4x3 cell} {4x3 cell} {4x3 cell} {4x3 cell} to extract rows 3 4 7 and 8 from each cell but in a much larger sequence, possibly building in the sequence of multiples of Row 3 (+ 4) and Row 4 (+4), i.e. B= {{7,8,9;10,11,12;19,20,21;22,23,24};{37,38,39;40,41,42;49,50,51;52,53,54};{67,68‌​,69;70,71,72;79,80,81;82,83,84};{97,98,99;100,101,102;109,110,111;112,113,114}}; –